# htaccess doesn't block some php drupal files

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal

I'm meeting a problem with .htaccess file. My application is developped with Drupal 7 and I want to block some php files like xmlrpc.php, install.php, update.php....

I try the following snippet but it doesn't work.

```
<FilesMatch "xmlrpc\.php|install\.php|update\.php">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks

PS : - It works with all kind of files except php files .
     - My Apache version is 2.4.2

Comment: My mistake : my Apache version is 2.4.4 !

Comment: Same effect with :   
`  RewriteRule ^(authorize\.php|xmlrpc\.php|xmlrpc\.php|web\.config|update\.php|install\.php|README\.txt|MAINTAINERS\.txt|LICENSE\.txt|INSTALL\.txt|INSTALL\.sqlite\.txt|INSTALL\.pgsql\.txt|INSTALL\.mysql\.txt|CHANGELOG\.txt|.txt) - [F,L,NC]
`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me with Apache 2.4.23.  Appending your code to line 10 of Drupal 7.53's `.htaccess` file prevents access to both `xmlrpc.php` and update.php.  Perhaps your particular placement of the code snippet allowed other logic in `.htaccess` to supersede?

Comment: I have ever tried to put it line 10 of .htaccess file without success :/

Comment: There's no difference between .htaccess file apache 2.4.2 and .htaccess file apache 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You can disable access to update.php via settings.php , you have a variable must be set by false :

```
$update_free_access = FALSE;
```

For install.php and xmlrpc.php, it's not necessary to block them , so why do you want to block them ?

Comment: I consider it's not necessary that they're in full view of everyone. I prefer blocking them just in case.

Comment: Make a "chmod 644" on it, it's a simple way .

Comment: Indeed, it's solution for production environment (involving modifications on deployment scripts). However, I would like undestand why I can't use .htaccess correctly and don't put this problem aside :D